# Make Https call using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

I have been using `HttpClient` for making WebApi calls using C#. Seems neat & fast way compared to `WebClient`. However I am stuck up while making `Https` calls.

How can I make below code to make `Https` calls?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foobar.com/");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

var task = httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync<DeviceRequest>(
                "api/SaveData", request);
```

**EDIT 1:**
The code above works fine for making http calls. But when I change the scheme to https it does not work. Here is the error obtained:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

**EDIT 2:**
Changing the scheme to https is: step one.

> How do I supply certificate & public / private key along with C#
>   request.

Comment: you are making https calls just by specifying `new Uri("https://foobar.com/");`

Comment: I'm confused. Does that not already work? Are you getting an error? (Edit: Posted before the OP changed the URI from https to http)

Answer (score 270, accepted):

If the server only supports higher TLS version like TLS 1.2 only, it will still fail unless your client PC is configured to use higher TLS version by default. To overcome this problem, add the following in your code:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Modifying your code example, it would be

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();   

//specify to use TLS 1.2 as default connection
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foobar.com/");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    
var task = httpClient.PostAsXmlAsync<DeviceRequest>("api/SaveData", request);
```

Comment: @DerekS Am glad and you're welcome. If for some reason, you cannot modify the code in the production setting but able to do some admin on the server, I use this utility to configure TLS 1.2 as default. https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto

Comment: `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` couldnt find those enum values you've mentioned

Comment: @JobaDiniz use .NET 4.5 or higher and include the System.Net namespace.

Comment: Does setting SecurityProtocol only need to occur once?  Like at application startup?

Comment: This works great. Thanks.   I also found that i did not need to clear any headers   used this                                                                                                 
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://...");

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Comment: This saved my ADP integration, more than 3.5 years after the fact! Thank you so much!

Comment: You don't have to use .Net 4.5 or higher though that makes it easier. You can also just find what the enum value for Tls1.2 is then do an explicit cast, say it was 3, then in < .Net 4.5 you could do *.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3; and it'll work. .net 4.5+ is still running on the 4.0 runtime its just that the version of the library you are using doesn't define that enum value, its still there in the framework though.

Answer (score 133):

Simply specify HTTPS in the URI.

```
new Uri("https://foobar.com/");
```

Foobar.com will need to have a trusted SSL cert or your calls will fail with untrusted error.

**EDIT Answer: [ClientCertificates with HttpClient](http://blog.sacaluta.com/2012/02/aspnet-web-api-httpclient-and-client.html)**

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
X509Certificate2 certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

**EDIT Answer2: If the server you are connecting to has disabled SSL, TLS 1.0, and 1.1 and you are still running .NET framework 4.5(or below) you need to make a choice**

1. Upgrade to .Net 4.6+ ([Supports TLS 1.2 by default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833123(v=vs.110).aspx#Net))
2. Add registry changes to instruct 4.5 to connect over TLS1.2 ( See: [salesforce writeup](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207#Inboundintegrations) for compat and keys to change OR checkout [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) see Ronald Ramos [answer comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33091871/343347))
3. Add application code to manually configure .NET to connect over TLS1.2 (see Ronald Ramos [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33091871/343347))

Comment: @felickz great response. is there any equivalent to WebRequestHandler library for windows phone 8?

Comment: @Billatron different libraries for WP / Win8 .. [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.clientcertificate.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @felickz have allready seen this though i was looking for some work around for windows phone 8 ! thanks anyway

Comment: @Billatron .. yeh i don't think it is going to happen as what i have used is a .NET object. As you are probably aware win phone uses silverlight/windows runtime implementation of some .net libraries but removes / overhauls others.

Comment: When developing or dealing with self signed certs you can ignore untrusted cert errors with the following:     `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
                    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`

Comment: What is `GetMyX509Certificate`?

Comment: @FandiSusanto A different topic... [See](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162194/Certificates-to-DB-and-Back)

Comment: @developer lets just hope that code doesn't slip into your production build :)

Comment: @felickz that's why I always wrap things like this with `#if DEBUG .... #endif`. I'd advise anyone else to do the same.

Comment: If using a client certificate `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` isn't called. See: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/17226

Answer (score 27):

There is a non-global setting at the level of `HttpClientHandler`:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Thus one enables latest TLS versions.

Note, that the default value `SslProtocols.Default` is actually `SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls` (checked for .Net Core 2.1 and  .Net Framework 4.7.1).

**Update:** In .Net 5.0 the default value for `HttpClientHandler.SslProtocols` is `None` whcih means the following (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols?view=net-5.0)):

> Allows the operating system to choose the best protocol to use, and to block protocols that are not secure. Unless your app has a specific reason not to, you should use this field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A little note: as per this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.sslprotocols?view=netframework-4.8
It's requiring at least framework 4.7.1.

Comment: @GELR yes, you're right. The above code yields a run-time error in .Net 4.6.1. Fixed the answer.

Comment: In previous versions of the .NET Framework, this property is private

Comment: On Net Core 3.1 this is all that worked for me.  Setting the global System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = xxx - had absolutely zero effect in a packet trace.

Answer (score 15):

Your code should be modified in this way:

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foobar.com/");
```

You have just to use the `https:` URI scheme.
There's a useful page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781240.aspx) on MSDN about the secure HTTP connections. Indeed:

> Use the https: URI scheme
>
> The HTTP Protocol defines two URI schemes:
>
> http : Used for unencrypted connections.
>
> https : Used for secure connections that should be encrypted. This option also uses digital certificates and certificate authorities to verify that the server is who it claims to be.

Moreover, consider that the HTTPS connections use a SSL certificate. Make sure your secure connection has this certificate otherwise the requests will fail.

**EDIT:**

> Above code works fine for making http calls. But when I change the
>   scheme to https it does not work, let me post the error.

What does it mean doesn't work? The requests fail? An exception is thrown? Clarify your question.

If the requests fail, then the issue should be the SSL certificate.

To fix the issue, you can use the class [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and then its property `ClientCertificate`.
Furthermore, you can find [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895971?wa=wsignin1.0) a useful sample about how to make a HTTPS request using the certificate.

An example is the following (as shown in the MSDN page linked before):

```
//You must change the path to point to your .cer file location. 
X509Certificate Cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\mycert.cer");
// Handle any certificate errors on the certificate from the server.
ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new CertPolicy();
// You must change the URL to point to your Web server.
HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://YourServer/sample.asp");
Request.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert);
Request.UserAgent = "Client Cert Sample";
Request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Preceisely, trick lies in sending certificates along with request. how to do that?

Comment: The link leads to a 404 page :(

Answer (score 15):

When connect to `https` I got this error too, I add this line before `HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();` and connect successfully:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

I know it from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/526730/4573839) and [Another Similar Anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553854/4573839) and the comment mentions:

> This is a hack useful in development so putting a #if DEBUG #endif statement around it is the least you should do to make this safer and stop this ending up in production

Besides, I didn't try the method in [Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2066735/4573839) that use `new X509Certificate()` or `new X509Certificate2()` to make a Certificate, I'm  not sure simply create by `new()` will work or not.

**EDIT:**  Some References:

[Create a Self-Signed Server Certificate in IIS 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(v=ws.10).aspx)

[Import and Export SSL Certificates in IIS 7](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm)

[Convert .pfx to .cer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403174/convert-pfx-to-cer)

[Best practices for using ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914305/best-practices-for-using-servercertificatevalidationcallback)

I find value of Thumbprint is equal to `x509certificate.GetCertHashString()`:

[Retrieve the Thumbprint of a Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-retrieve-the-thumbprint-of-a-certificate)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem when connecting to GitHub, which requires a user agent. Thus it is sufficient to provide this rather than generating a certificate

```
var client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
    "Authorization",
    "token 123456789307d8c1d138ddb0848ede028ed30567");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
    "User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: you should revoke that token that you have been sharing with the internet , I think GitHub may have done that automatically.

Comment: do you really think my token starts with `123456789` ??

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and in my case the solution was stupidly simple: open Visual Studio with Administrator rights. I tried all the above solutions and it didn't work until I did this. Hope it saves someone some precious time.

Comment: Since you're new to the site, you may not know that if an answer has the green check next to it, that means that it was accepted by OP as the correct solution for his/her problem. Unless you can give a better, more complete answer, it's probably best to not submit another answer, especially on such an old question.

Comment: Well, I had the issue too, and the green checked answer didn't help at all. Thought I give an alternative solution which helped me, but hey, I won't do it next time. Thanks for the minus points ;) have a great day.

Answer (score 3):

Just specifying HTTPS in the URI should do the trick.

```
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://foobar.com/");
```

If the request works with HTTP but fails with HTTPS then **this is most certainly a certificate issue**. Make sure the caller trusts the certificate issuer and that the certificate is not expired. A quick and easy way to check that is to try making the query in a browser.

You also may want to check on the server (if it's yours and / or if you can) that it is set to serve HTTPS requests properly.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the error:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

... with a **Xamarin Forms Android**-targeting application attempting to request resources from an API provider that required **TLS 1.3.**

The solution was to update the project configuration to swap out the Xamarin "managed" (.NET) http client (that doesn't support TLS 1.3 as of Xamarin Forms v2.5), and instead use the android native client.

It's a simple project toggle in visual studio. See screenshot below.

- Project Properties
- Android Options
- Advanced
- List item
- Change "HttpClient implementation" to "Android"
- Change SSL/TLS implementation to "Native TLS 1.2+"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the **ModernHttpClient** Nuget Package: After downloading the package, you can implement it like this:

```
 var handler = new ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler()
 {
     UseProxy = true,
 };


 handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
 handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work form me. The solution was to enable TLS 1.3 by switching from the xamarin managed http client to the android-native http client. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below declarations to your class:

```
public const SslProtocols _Tls12 = (SslProtocols)0x00000C00;
public const SecurityProtocolType Tls12 = (SecurityProtocolType)_Tls12;
```

After:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

And:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 /*| SecurityProtocolType.Tls */| Tls12;
```

Happy? :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with felickz but also i want to add an example for clarifying the usage in c#. I use SSL in windows service as follows.

```
    var certificatePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin");
    gateway = new GatewayService();
    gateway.PreAuthenticate = true;


    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath + @"\Attached\my_certificate.pfx","certificate_password");
    gateway.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    gateway.UserAgent = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    gateway.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
```

If I'm going to use it in a web application, I'm just changing the implementation on the proxy side like this:

```
public partial class GatewayService : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol // to => Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working code that works in HTTPS call too**

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("https://yourdomain.com/");
builder.Query = "id=10";                 
//Create a query
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;                  
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", userprofile.Token);                
var result = client.GetAsync(builder.Uri).Result;                                       
using (StreamReader sr = new 
StreamReader(result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
{                       
   responseres = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score -5):

For error:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I think that you need to accept certificate unconditionally with following code

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

as [Oppositional](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029/oppositional) wrote in his answer to question [.NET client connecting to ssl Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15206507/723741).

Comment: This is bypassing cert validation. Do not ever do this in production.

Comment: Well @JohnKorsnes, if Abhijeet is accessing some public WebAPI server, I don't think that he can do much about it. This was my case.