# PostAsJsonAsync returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asmx, fiddler

I am currently posting a json string to an API to receive an object containing various values.

This is the json string i am posting:

```
{"SomeProperty":1,"DimensionOne":4,"DimensionTwo":6,"IdNumber":0}
```

Now I don't have issues with the Json string itself because I've tested this string in Fiddler going to the api, and it works perfectly fine, returning all the values I need.

The only difference between what I am doing and what Fiddler is doing is that I am going from the script to a WebService that posts to the API.

Here is the code I am using for the WebService:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public ObjectType Relay(string json)
    {
        const string url = "https://api.com";
        var client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = new Uri(url)};

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1/GetObject", json).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var objectRequest = Task.FromResult(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectType>(objectRequest.Result.Result);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So far it has only returned null (obviously because response.IsSuccessStatusCode is not TRUE)

But when I comment out the if brackets and remove the return null, it gives me an empty object when I should be receiving data. All the inputs are correct.

I'm wondering if I should be using a method other than PostAsJsonAsync, or if there is anything else I should be doing to the json string or json header.

Again, the json string is in correct format as it worked with Fiddler and has previously worked when going directly from the website to the API (without a WebService).

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're sending a https request, you need a certificate for your HttpClient: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient

Comment: looking into that @KhanhTO thank you for the quick response

Comment: @KhanhTO i would suggest posting that as an answer b/c it may very well be the solution. i would like to give you an upvote as well.

Comment: did the answer work for you?

Comment: @KhanhTO ah I forgot update with the solution. Unfortunately your solution did not fix it but that fortunately that wasn't an issue. The parameters of my Web Method in regards to the json object I was sending were the cause. I will update later with a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending a https request. Although client certificate is optional in the protocol, but you need a certificate for your HttpClient **in case the server requires it**: [Make Https call using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)