# How do you send a certificate with an HttpRequestMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate

Here I have an HttpRequestMessage, and I am trying to add a client certificate to it, but cannot seem to find how to do this.  Has anyone out there done something like this?

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "myapi/?myParm=" + aParm);
//Want to add a certificate to request - a .p12 file in my project
myAPIResponse res = await SendAndReadAsAsync<myAPIResponse>(request, aCancelToken);
```

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient

Comment: Yup, this one appears to be sending it with the HttpClient...I was hoping to see if it is possible to send it with the HttpRequestMessage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an answer combining HttpClient with HttpRequestMessage.

The HttpRequestMessage holding the data and client handling how the data is sent.

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
X509Certificate certificate = GetMyX509Certificate();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage (HttpMethod.Get, "myapi/?myParm=" + aParm);
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync (request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

**Edit**: Here is a link explaining the difference between WebRequestHandler, HttpClientHandler & HttpClient to understand which one you should use when: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/henrikn/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-webrequesthandler-explained

Comment: Thank you :) I will give it a try!

Comment: This is now HttpClientHandler

Comment: @irhetoric you cannot add Certificates to the HttpClientHandler however.