# C# POST request to webapi using a console program

Tags: c#, api, post, console, http-post

I have a web api that I can access successfully through a browser :-

https://127.0.0.1:8443/ncrApi

I am trying to create a simple console program in C# using VS2015 to send data and receive a response using http POST.

Here is what I have so far:-

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebSample
{

    class ApiSendData
    {
        public string ApiFunction { get; set; }
        public string DppName { get; set; }
        public string ClearData { get; set; }
        public string DppVersion { get; set; }
    }



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // The Main function calls an async method named RunAsync 
            // and then blocks until RunAsyncc completes.
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // This code sets the base URI for HTTP requests, 
                // and sets the Accept header to "application/json", 
                // which tells the server to send data in JSON format.
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:8443/ncrApi");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


                // HTTP POST
                var datatobeSent = new ApiSendData()
                                    {
                                        ApiFunction ="NcrSecureData",
                                        DppName ="CSampleCustomer",
                                        DppVersion ="Latest",
                                        ClearData ="1234567890"
                                    };

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("ncrApi", datatobeSent);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Get the URI of the created resource.
                    Uri ncrUrl = response.Headers.Location;

                    // do whatever you need to do here with the returned data //


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I am getting an error on the HttpResonseMessage response statement....{"An error occurred while sending the request."}
{"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}

I suspect it is because I am not correctly understanding the the client.BaseAddress and the HttpResponseMessage response statements.

Here is what I have been following:-
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Additional comments:-
1) I turned SSL off and successfully connected to the web api on port 8080. 
2) I successfully connected to other SSL api's with my code.

Seems like the C# code doesn't connect to ncrApi on SSL connection..any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting an error because the final address is your baseAddress + post address, that is: http://localhost:8443/nrcApi/nrcApi , which doesn't exist

Try changing your client.BaseAddress to:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:8443/");
```

For SSL connection errors, try generating a trusted certificate: 
[Make https call using httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)

Comment: thanks. I tried that and same error. However this time I turned off SSL. and just connected to localhost:8080/ncrapi and that worked. I tried connecting to other SSL api's and my program successfully connects with them

Comment: and have you correctly configured your ncrapi endpoint to accept incoming SSL connections on port 8443? It could be some server side issue related to your endpoint.

Comment: I have just found this, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient

It can also be that you don't have a trusted certificate ...

Comment: thanks!! that solved my issue. I am getting a 200 OK response now. But no data. lol the conundrums continue

Comment: alright! can you mark it as answer please? I will edit with the reference

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok. However, the issue seems to be the call you are making. Basically in the following call, the first parameter is the method/function to be invoked after your URI.

> HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("ncrApi",
> datatobeSent);

In this case **ncrApi** is your method. Calling it in the base URL will result in it being added to the final call making it give an address to an endpoint that does not exist.