# using HttpClient.GetAsync inside a service fabric service throws "unable to connect to remote service" exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am running service fabric in local cluster. And I use HttpClient.GetAsync to access https://google.com. Do I have to change any configuration to allow service fabric to talk to remote service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If you can do it an a console app, you can do it in a Service Fabric service.

Question is more about connecting over HTTPS with HttpClient. See here: [Make Https call using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)

Or check your Internet connection.