# C# Flurl - Add WebRequestHandler to FlurlClient

Tags: c#, http, authentication, x509certificate2, flurl

I am working with [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/) to hit an API that requires certificate-based authentication. I have seen from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient) that adding a certificate to a `WebRequestHandler` and instructing an `HttpClient` to use this handler is easy.

However, it is not so clear for me using Flurl. I have tried the follwing three things.

**Extending DefaultHttpFactory**

I first suspected that I needed to create my own `X509HttpFactory : DefaultHttpFactory` which would create the handler and assign it to the `HttpClient`. However, in viewing the source, I notice that the constructor for `CreateClient` already expects a handler. Where does this handler come from?

**Creating Client using DefaultHttpFactory**

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(myX509Cert);
var clientFactory = new DefaultHttpClientFactory();
FlurlClient fc = clientFactory.CreateClient(url, handler);
```

This does not compile as `HttpClient` cannot be casted to `FlurlClient`

**Use ConfigureHttpClient**

```
var clientFactory = new DefaultHttpClientFactory();
FlurlClient fc = new Url("foobar.com").ConfigureHttpClient(client => client = clientFactory
  .CreateClient(url, handler));
```

This seems like the most viable option, but I'm unsure since the delegate is an `Action` with no return type.

**The Question**

What is the best/correct way to support client-side certificate authentication using Flurl?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close - a custom factory is definitely the way to go. But you want to override `CreateMessageHandler` rather than `CreateClient`:

```
public class X509HttpFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly X509Certificate2 _cert;

    public X509HttpFactory(X509Certificate2 cert) {
        _cert = cert;
    }

    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler() {
        var handler = base.CreateMessageHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(_cert);
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Then you can either register it globally (on app startup):

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings => {
    settings.HttpClientFactory = new X509HttpFactory(myCert);
});
```

Or for all calls to a particular host:

```
FlurlHttp.ConfigureClient(ROOT_URL, cli => {
    cli.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new X509HttpFactory(myCert);
});
```

Or for a new `FlurlClient`:

```
var cli = new FlurlClient(url)
    .Configure(settings => settings.HttpClientFactory = new X509HttpFactory(myCert));
```

Or an existing one:

```
cli.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new X509HttpFactory(myCert);
```

Comment: Thanks. Awesome library!

Comment: If I have more than one URL, what is the configuration?
For example, I apply it to web crawlers
I visit http://exampledomain.com
After logging in to the system, it redirects to another address like https://otherdomain.com (1) or https://anotherdomain.net (2)
And I do on both of these domains, how to configure baseAddress
Domain (1) and (2) are unknown, depending on their server navigation

Comment: @mincasoft I think the first way I showed how to register it (globally) is the way to go.

Comment: I am not getting reference to add webRequestHandler, what should be done?

Comment: Looks like WebRequestHandler is available in .net Framework, any solution for .net core (.net 5)

Comment: handler doesnt show up ClientCertificates property. I'm using Flurl 4 in Xamarin. Is it removed? What is the way of certificate validation in Flurl pls help @ToddMenier

Comment: `if (handler is HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler)
 {
     httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(_cert);
 }`