# Disable AutoRedirect in FlurlClient

Tags: redirect, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi, flurl

I am using [FlurlHttp](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/) and I want to disable AllowAutoRedirect for some API calls.
I know [How can I get System.Net.Http.HttpClient to not follow 302 redirects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453892/how-can-i-get-system-net-http-httpclient-to-not-follow-302-redirects)

```
WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
webRequestHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler);
// Send a request using GetAsync or PostAsync
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com")
```

But for Flurl I found only the way similar to described in
[C# Flurl - Add WebRequestHandler to FlurlClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033337/c-sharp-flurl-add-webrequesthandler-to-flurlclient) (I haven't compiled yet the code below , so it may have some errors)

```
public class HttpClientFactoryWithWebRequestHandler : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    private readonly WebRequestHandler _webRequestHandler;

    public HttpClientFactoryWithWebRequestHandler (WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler ) 
    {
        _webRequestHandler = webRequestHandler ;
    }

    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        var handler =_webRequestHandler ;
//Or    var handler = new WebRequestHandler(_webRequestHandler );
        return handler;
    }
}
```

Then I can pass the setting for a new FlurlClient:

```
WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
webRequestHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var fc = new FlurlClient(url)
    .ConfigureClient(c => c.HttpClientFactory = 
                  new HttpClientFactoryWithWebRequestHandler (webRequestHandler));
```

It looks more complicated that it could be. Is it the right way to do or it can be done  simplier?

UPDATE 2021: Flurl now supports out of the box

`await url.WithAutoRedirect(false).GetAsync()`;

See more options in https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#redirects

Comment: Is it ok to disable redirects on all clients app-wide?

Comment: @ToddMenier, For current task it's OK, because the client is a microservice running as separate small MVC site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flurl now supports this natively:

```
"https://example.com"
  .WithAutoRedirect(false)
  [...]
```

Documentation: https://flurl.dev/docs/configuration/#redirects

Answer (score 6):

***This answer is obsolete as of Flurl 3.0. Per the accepted answer, Flurl now [supports](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/500) a wealth of redirect features out the box.***

---

It feels a little heavy because it's a scenario that Flurl doesn't support directly, so it requires tinkering under the hood a bit. You're on the right track but I think there's a few ways you could simplify it. First, I'd suggest creating the `WebRequestHandler` inside the factory. Creating it externally and passing it in seems unnecessary.

```
public class NoRedirectHttpClientFactory : DefaultHttpClientFactory
{
    public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
    {
        return new WebRequestHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = false };
    }
}
```

If you want this behavior app-wide by default, you could register it globally on startup. Then you don't need to do anything with individual `FlurlClient`s.

```
FlurlHttp.Configure(settings =>
    settings.HttpClientFactory = new NoRedirectHttpClientFactory());
```

Otherwise, if you need the ability to pick and choose which `FlurlClient`s you disable it for, an extension method would make it a little easier:

```
public static IFlurlClient WithoutRedirects(this IFlurlClient fc) {
    fc.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new NoRedirectHttpClientFactory();
    return fc;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
new FlurlClient(url).WithoutRedirects()...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but `FlurlClient.HttpClient.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` and `client.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` will not work.    AllowAutoRedirect is a property of [HttpClientHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.110).aspx), not HttpClient.  
I wish to have `FlurlClient.HttpClientHandler` property.

Answer (score 3):

My implementation is based on Todd's answer (minor class/method name changes)

Example of use:

```
var resp = await new FlurlClient(url).DisableRedirects().Request().AllowAnyHttpStatus().GetAsync();
resp.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.Found);//302
```

Implementation:

```
 public class HttpClientFactoryWithWebRequestHandler : DefaultHttpClientFactory
    {
        private readonly HttpMessageHandler _httpMessageHandler;
        public HttpClientFactoryWithWebRequestHandler(HttpMessageHandler httpMessageHandler) 
        {
            _httpMessageHandler = httpMessageHandler;
        }

        public override HttpMessageHandler CreateMessageHandler()
        {
            var handler = _httpMessageHandler;
            return handler;
        }
    }
    public static class FlurlClientExtensions
    {
        public static IFlurlClient DisableRedirects(this IFlurlClient fc)
        {
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler {AllowAutoRedirect = false};
            fc.Settings.HttpClientFactory = new HttpClientFactoryWithWebRequestHandler(httpClientHandler);
            return fc;
        }
    }
```