# salesforce owin oauth login returns an unauthorized response

Tags: c#, oauth, salesforce, owin

I am currently trying to authenticate salesforce users on my web app using an owin security provider.

**UPDATE**: by adding `salesforceOptions.CallbackPath =  new PathString("/callback");` to the Startup.Auth.cs file, I can navigate to the login screen. However when I enter the my credentials, I get returned to the login page. function `AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfo();` returns null.

> **Salesforce settings (sample):**
>   consumer key = abc
>   consumer secret = def
>   Selected OAuth scopes = basic (id, profile, email, address phone)
>   Callback url = http://localhost:12345/callback http://localhost:12345/account/externallogin 
>   Enable for device flow = false
>   Require secret for web server flow = true
>   include custom attributes = false
>   include custom permissions = false
>
> **Creating the solution:**
>   I created a MVC app with indivicual user authentication in vs 2015.
>   I added the NugetPackage Owin.Security.Providers.Salesforce

```
// Startup.Auth.cs class
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Generated code
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });            
       app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
       app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
       app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        // I added this
        var salesforceOptions = new SalesforceAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Endpoints =
               new SalesforceAuthenticationOptions.SalesforceAuthenticationEndpoints
               {
                   AuthorizationEndpoint =
                       "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize",
                   TokenEndpoint = "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
               },
            ClientId = "abc",
            ClientSecret = "def"
        };
        // I added the following to get one step further:
        salesforceOptions.CallbackPath =  new PathString("/callback");
        app.UseSalesforceAuthentication(salesforceOptions);
    }
}
```

No changes where made to the web.config or any other file. When I run the application I receive a salesforce login button. When I press this button and enter my credentials, I get redirected to the Login page, with no login details.

The function that I expect to return my LoginInfo is in the account controller:
`var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`

What settings could i be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unauthorized response was a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring). It had nothing to do with this. I received the same 401 during the google login but that worked fine

I found the answer to the problem to the issue. I managed to find a message hidden in the logging that told me the following:

> **Stronger security is required**
>
> To access this website, update your web browser or upgrade your operating system to support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.

TSL => “Transport Layer Security.”

After googling this, I managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient) solution. By adding the following line to my startup code, I solved my issue:

```
using System.Net;

public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
        // rest of Startup.Auth.cs code
    }
}
```

After I did that I could log in normally.