# How to create HTTPS request on UnitTest class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, https

I created a Unit Test class for testing a simple HTTPS request

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{

    string destination = "...";
    string message = "..";
    string accountUsername = "..";
    string accountPassword = "..";
    string senderPhoneNumber = "...";

    HttpStatusCode response = await SMSProvider.Send(destination, message, accountUsername, accountPassword, senderPhoneNumber);

    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout, response);
}
```

And the SMS Provider is a Library class

```
public static async Task<HttpStatusCode> Send(String destination, String message, String accountUsername, String accountPassword, String senderPhoneNumber)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "username", accountUsername },
        { "password", accountPassword }, 
        { "src", senderPhoneNumber },
        { "dst", destination },
        { "text", message },
        { "srr", "3" }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

    HttpStatusCode responseStatus = HttpStatusCode.Accepted;

    try
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https:SPECIFIC-URL-HERE", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        responseStatus = response.StatusCode;
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        string error = we.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string error = e.ToString();
    }


    return responseStatus;
}
```

However it throws the following error

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

How can i send an HTTPS request? 
Do I need a certificate or something?

Comment: Is this of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient/33091871

Comment: Just tried that approach now :D Still not working =(

Comment: Have you checked the certificate to make sure it's trusted?

Comment: What certificate? I'm kinda newbie to this. As far as I know, the server has a certificate, which contains the public key (theory I think). Do I need to install something?

Comment: If you want to talk to the server via HTTPS then it must have a trusted certificate installed, or an untrusted one that they share with you and you use in your application.  Open the Url in your browser (using HTTPS) and to the left of the Url you should have an indication that it's secure (usually a padlock).  Check that first.

Comment: Ok let me see if I get it. The server I'm trying to reach, needs to have a certificate, either trusted by a CA or not, but what matters is that I have that certificate installed on my machine too? Kinda weird. It would mean that for every website I was trying to access I would need to have the certificate pre-installed...

Comment: No - the server needs a trusted certificate *or* you both have the same untrusted one.  Can you open the Url in a browser, using HTTPS?

Comment: No, I can not =/

Comment: If it doesn't serve HTTPS then you can't successfully request HTTPS.  Did you think you can just request over a secure connection anywhere you like?

Comment: Yeah I though it was like.
Me: Hi, I want to securely communicate with you. Prove me I can trust you please.
Server: Here is a certificate from a CA that proves i'm trustworthy.

And then we would proceed

Comment: Fair enough - at least now you know :)