# Using C# to authenticate an SSL certificate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ssl, https, certificate

I'm trying to communicate with a backend server using SSL.
I'm trying using HttpClient from the System.Net.Http library, but I couldn't get it working.
This is my code (Debug.Log is just a print since I'm using Unity):

```
public static async Task DownloadPageAsync(string web)
 {
     try
     {
         HttpClient cl = new HttpClient();
         string body = await cl.GetStringAsync(new Uri(web));

         Debug.Log(web);
     }
     catch (HttpRequestException e)
     {
         Debug.Log(e.InnerException.Message);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Debug.Log(ex.ToString());
     }
 }
```

When I try it in a web with a bad certificate, it gives: "Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)", which is fine. The problem is that good certificates also triggers an error: "Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)".

I've saw other answers saying that simply accepting all the certificates works fine, but I need to check if it's a valid certificate or not.

¿Is there a way of doing it with HttpClient? ¿Or with some other class?

Btw, I'm only using it to send POST request, and receiving a simple string.

Thank you!

Comment: Where did you specify the client certificate? Once you specify it you can enable capi2, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2013/09/30/enable-capi2-event-logging-to-troubleshoot-pki-and-ssl-certificate-issues/ for troubleshooting

Comment: I didn't know that I need to specify the client certificate as I didn't saw it in the MSDN example. Is there an example of doing it?

Comment: You need if you use certificate based authentication. https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.pedrofelix.org/2012/12/16/using-httpclient-with-ssltls/amp/

Comment: Okey, I'll try it

Comment: I just tried it using the HttpClientHandler (the WebRequestHandler gives me an error) and it gives the same error. It also added a new error, in which a web with a expired cert is the only one that works.

Comment: Use then CAPI2 and EventViewer to get more insights about the error...

Comment: I'm not getting anything logged in the EventViewer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Https call using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

For [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) since `Unity 2018.1` there is the [`UnityWebRequest.certificateHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest-certificateHandler.html) e.g.

```
IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
     UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
     request.certificateHandler = new AcceptAllCertificatesSignedWithASpecificPublicKey();

     yield return request.SendWebRequest ();
     if (request.isNetworkError)
     {
         Debug.Log("Something went wrong, and returned error: " + request.error);
     }
     else
     {
         // Show results as text
         Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
     }
}
```

And the implementation of the example `CertificateHandler`:

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
// Based on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning#.Net
class AcceptAllCertificatesSignedWithASpecificPublicKey: CertificateHandler
{
    // Encoded RSAPublicKey
    private static string PUB_KEY = "mypublickey";
    protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData)
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateData);
        string pk = certificate.GetPublicKeyString();
        if (pk.ToLower().Equals(PUB_KEY.ToLower()))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

([Source](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1479862/unitywebrequest-tomcat-redirect-and-self-signed-ss.html))

---

For `HttpClient` see [Make Https call using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)

Comment: I tried it and works fine, but I have one question. SSL communication is encrypted, so using HTTPS with UnityWebRequest encrypts the connection?