# Can use TLS1.1 certificate for the TLS1.2 connection?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, tls1.2, dotnet-httpclient

My donet application calling to the server which was supporting TLS1.1 protocol but now the TLS version is change. the current TLS version is TLS1.2. after upgrading the TLS1.2 protocol the connection is break. not able to call server api.
can use old certificate (TLS1.1) to connect TLS1.2 protocol?
I already updated the detent framework 4.6

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient

Comment: thanks for help Nagib, please correct me. no need to update TLS certificate only need to upgrade framework and add one line of code is enough. is it?