# Call API with header in c#

Tags: c#, api

i was trying to receive the response after API call without success.
tha API call needs header.
this is my code:

```
        private static readonly string url = "https://evtradepro.net/wp-json/mp/v1/me";
    public static async Task<string> Authorization()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(url);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MEMBERPRESS-API-KEY: WWWWWWWW", "application/json"); 
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        HttpContent content = response.Content;
        string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return mycontent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add() takes two arguments: the first is the key, and the second is the value

Comment: thank you, the line of client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add() was fixed, but i have this error: "Impossible de créer un canal sécurisé SSL/TLS."

Comment: TLS issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient