# Unable to send SMS using twilio in C#

Tags: c#, .net, twilio

I tried to send SMS using the sample code from the twilio website but I am getting an error "Invalid TLS protocol". I had used valid accountsid, authtoken and verified mobile numbers.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            body: "Hi there",
            from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15017122661"),
            to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("+15558675310")
        );

        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a valid https site to be able to send http request to https backends.

Comment: related issue here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? What operating system are you using and what version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparantly by adding this line to code before sending request it fixed. To see more information go to related issue in this link:

[Http Client for https endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Comment: I have changed the framework to 4.5 and added the two lines code, ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;