# Sending HTTPS request from DLL in C#

Tags: c#, https

I really have no idea about the issue here.
I have a DLL to send requests to an HTTPS server and get response with below C# code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The DLL is with a standard interface. If this is called from my C# application, I got an error when read string from the response, sayiny "input string was not in a correct format". But if the URL is HTTP (not HTTPS) or it is called from a standard commercial application, it works.
Any help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: Cna you share the code of using the DLL?

Comment: Is the exception on line `GetAsync` or `ReadAsStringAsync`

Comment: Chetan - it is a standard framework. So I'm not calling the DLL directly but follow its' interface, in which the DLL is calling there.

Comment: clamchoda - it is on the line of ReadAsStringAsync

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Https call using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)

Comment: Thank you @SohaibJundi, but still the same :(