# httpClient GetAsync call fails for Https with OpenSSL internal error: refcount error

Tags: linux, .net-core

In Linux, following code fails :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync("https://www.google.com").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Error: OpenSSL internal error: refcount error

But following passes:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Why `http` passes but `https` causes problem? This is happening only in Linux, In Windows it works fine.

I am using `.Net 6.0` on `Ubuntu 20.04`

I am expecting the `https` call to go through but the app keep crashing with the "`refcount error`".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make Https call using HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251689/make-https-call-using-httpclient)

Comment: Not really. I am using .Net 6.0 and publishing the .net dll with following configuration
dotnet publish ccc.csproj -c Debug -r linux-x64 --self-contained true -o ./publish