# How to configure number of TCP connections using dotnet (nugget package) httpclient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I used to use HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx) to configure number of TCP connections opened by client.

I am planning to use HttpCLient for my new Application. However I couldn't find related information on how to configure number of TCP connections. I thought it would be exposed through one of the properties in **webrequesthandler** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.webrequesthandler.aspx, [Allowing Untrusted SSL Certificates with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient)) however I couldn't find it. Looks like it can't be configured through a custom httpclient message handler as well (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/httpclient-message-handlers)

### Question

How to configure number of TCP (persisted) connections?

### Update 1

Looks like it is not exposed through HttpClient (after analyzing the code through ILSpy). However, looks like i can use FindServicePoint method of ServicePointManager. Can any one please confirm if this is the way to go - by finding the service point for my uri and setting the connection limit?

```
public static ServicePoint FindServicePoint(Uri address)
{
    return ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(address, null);
}
```

### Update 2

In fact, looks like that is the way to go as `HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint` internally is invoking the same method. Below is the corresponding code snippet from ILSpy - however there are quite a few `servicepointmanager.findservicepoint(..)` overload methods - picking the right one may be tricky.

```
Monitor.Enter(this, ref flag);
            if (this._ServicePoint == null || forceFind)
            {
                if (!this.ProxySet)
                {
                    this._Proxy = WebRequest.InternalDefaultWebProxy;
                }
                if (this._ProxyChain != null)
                {
                    this._ProxyChain.Dispose();
                }
                this._ServicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(this._Uri, this._Proxy, out this._ProxyChain, ref this._AbortDelegate, ref this.m_Aborted);
                if (Logging.On)
                {
                    Logging.Associate(Logging.Web, this, this._ServicePoint);
                }
            }
```

### Note

I do not want to use `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` as it's global. I am looking for something related to `httpwebrequest.servicepoint.connectionlimit` which is local to the request and effects per service point (host).

Comment: Yes the global value affects HttpClient.  Why don't you want to use ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit ?

Comment: @Darell, thanks for the confirmation (btw, i have looked at the code through ILSpy last week to confirm the same - removed that statement now  from the qtn to avoid irrelevant info). I didn't want to use ServicePointMnager.Defaultconnectionlimit as it has global impact. My app talks with multiple services - so wanted to control service points locally for each of them (just like the way httpwebrequest.servicepoint). But, it is not a deal breaker - as i can use FindServicePoint(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SemphoreSlim to control the entry points in your code that creates the request which in turn creates the TCP ports.

[How to limit the amount of concurrent async I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806951/how-to-limit-the-amount-of-concurrent-async-i-o-operations)