# Untrusted certificates with HttpClient in a PCL

Tags: c#, ssl, xamarin, portable-class-library

Right now i am using HttpClient in a Portable Class Library to access websites. Some of these may not have a trusted https-certificate, so when trying to access these sites i get multiple Exceptions.

I found this: [Allowing Untrusted SSL Certificates with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient) but all the solutions used classes or references that are not available to me.

Please also correct me if i misunderstood something, certificates, https etc are not really topics i am familiar with.

Comment: Create a dependency service, on the native projects construct the httpclient with the needed modifications and pass it to the PCL through the dependency service.