# How can I use "System.Net.ServicePointManager" in .net core？

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, move

I have a trouble:

ASP.NET 4.0 has the class `System.Net.ServicePointManager`, but I can't find it in .NET core.

How to find it?

Comment: I can't find the class "ServicePointManager" in namespace "System.Net"

Comment: What do you need it for? There may be an alternate solution.

Comment: I want to tell a client request not to care about the remote servers self created SSL cert. In .net 4.0 I'm able to do this by manipulating the System.Net.ServicePointManager. How can I do the same in .net core?

Comment: My core: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CheckValidationResult); private static bool CheckValidationResult(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors errors)
        {
            return true; //allways true
        }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bypass invalid SSL certificate in .net core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138952/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-in-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like  it is currently not supported. For more information, please take a look at [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10727)

> Currently, there is no way to control connection level properties for
>   TCP connections in the .NET Core stack except for some small
>   properties on HttpClientHandler like MaxConnectionsPerServer.

EDIT: from [the blog post on ASP.NET Core 2.0 Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserveroptions.limits?view=aspnetcore-1.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_KestrelServerOptions_Limits)

> The Kestrel web server has new features that make it more suitable as an Internet-facing server. We’ve added a number of server constraint configuration options in the KestrelServerOptions class’s new Limits property. You can now add limits for the following:
>
> 1. Maximum client connections
> 2. Maximum request body size
> 3. Minimum request body data rate