# IdentityServer4 Ignore SSL Errors when obtaining configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

My dev environment, the auth server has an invalid SSL cert.  When my client tried to get the OpenId config from `https://auth-server/.well-known/openid-configuration` I get the following error:

```
WinHttpException: A security error occurred
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://auth-server/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever+<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()

InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://auth-server/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
```

Here is how I configure IdentityServer4:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = authority;
        options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;
        options.ApiSecret = secret;
        //change this to true for SSL
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    });
```

Is there any way to disable cert validation in this scenario?

Comment: If you are in the dev environment, why don't you use http:// auth-server/.well-known/openid-configuration

Comment: I'm assuming you mean 'http' instead of 'https'.  Unfortunately, I don't have controller over that.

Comment: It seems to me that this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712844/ignore-bad-certificate-net-core

Comment: what happnes if you put http://auth-server/.well-known/openid-configuration  in a browser with the identity server running?  have you checked its logs?