# X509Chain error on .NET Core running on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, ssl, .net-core

I've developed an application using .net core 2.1 and C#, in this app I call an API over HTTPS (SSL) in the Windows Version the Self Contained app works ok but on Mac I got the following error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be
>   established, see inner exception. --->
>   System.PlatformNotSupportedException: X509Chain    at
>   Internal.Cryptography.Pal.SecTrustChainPal.PreparePoliciesArray(Boolean
>   checkRevocation)    at
>   Internal.Cryptography.Pal.SecTrustChainPal.OpenTrustHandle(ICertificatePal
>   leafCert, X509Certificate2Collection extraStore, X509RevocationMode
>   revocationMode)    at
>   Internal.Cryptography.Pal.ChainPal.BuildChain(Boolean
>   useMachineContext, ICertificatePal cert, X509Certificate2Collection
>   extraStore, OidCollection applicationPolicy, OidCollection
>   certificatePolicy, X509RevocationMode revocationMode,
>   X509RevocationFlag revocationFlag, DateTime verificationTime, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2
>   certificate, Boolean throwOnException)    at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2
>   certificate)    at
>   System.Net.CertificateValidationPal.VerifyCertificateProperties(SafeDeleteContext
>   securityContext, X509Chain chain, X509Certificate2 remoteCertificate,
>   Boolean checkCertName, Boolean isServer, String hostName)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(RemoteCertValidationCallback
>   remoteCertValidationCallback, ProtocolToken& alertToken)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake(ProtocolToken&
>   alertToken)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
>   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__47_1(IAsyncResult
>   iar)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream
>   stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)

Comment: `X509Chain`: I guess the problem comes from not having the same CAs in your trust stores in both cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore bad certificate - .NET CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712844/ignore-bad-certificate-net-core)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue in the following post here in stackOverflow

[Ignore bad certificate - .NET CORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712844/ignore-bad-certificate-net-core)