# Connecting to ODBC driver from azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am currently working on an azure function that connects to a odbc driver. I have one locally called 'Dobbe WMS productie' and i am using the following code to connect to it.

```
using(odbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Dobbe WMS productie"))
{
    conn.Open();
    // performs some actions
    conn.Close();
}
```

Locally this works just fine. Now I published this to azure and it is not working, as i expected. The problem is, I cant find anything to solve my issue. Is there anyone that can help me with this?

**EDIT:**
My full error message: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

I opened the ODBC-datasources on windows -> System-DSN -> add and then choose the postgresql ansi driver. Filled out the basics in the form and clicked on save

I have also tried Npgsl and got the following error:  `The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.` my connection string looks something like this: `Server=address;Port=5432;Database=dbname;User Id=username;Password=password;SslMode=Require`

Comment: `I cant find anything to solve my issue` did you deploy the driver? Did you create the data source? What error did you get?

Comment: Hello @PanagiotisKanavos , thanks for your quik response! I havent done anything such as deploying it. If you have a reference to some documentation I would really appreciate it. Also take a look at the edit

Comment: Well, did you read what the error says? How do you expect to connect to a data source that doesn't exist? `a reference to some documentation` how did you set up the data source on your machine?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know what it says. I expected an error like this because i have a driver local. But i dont know where to start to be able to access it from azure

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I opened the ODBC-datasources on windows -> System-DSN -> add and then choose the postgresql ansi driver. Filled out the basics in the form and clicked on save

Comment: I'm curious. Where will that postgresql database be when you have deployed your azure function in Azure?

Comment: @rene, the postgresql database is a cloud database. But I dont own it. We got instructions from another company to connect to it

Comment: Shouldn't you use the native .net driver: https://www.npgsql.org/ instead of Odbc? That at least reduces your deployment dependencies a bit.

Comment: @rene I have tried this to. Please take a look at the edit

Comment: I highly doubt you will ever be able to use an ODBC driver in an Azure function. ODBC drivers require an local installation step that I doubt is feasible within an azure function, given how those get packaged, deployed and managed. You not only need the ODBC components but also the native bridge.

Comment: the remote certificate issue is solvable by adding a custom cert validation on the servicepoint manager. Assuming you have an unwilling server administrator to properly  configure cetifiicates on their end.

Comment: @rene Do you have any examples of this? Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712844/ignore-bad-certificate-net-core  and more on https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+servicepointmanager+certificate+is%3Aq+answers%3A1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of @rene I managed to get this working with NpgSQL. After some digging into service point manager I found out I had to do one small thing. Which is modifying the connection string to something like this:

`Server=address;Port=5432;Database=dbname;User Id=username;Password=password;SslMode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true`