# Getting "Unable to find type [System.Net.ServicePointManager]." in PowerShell for OS X

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

I'm trying to debug a script that makes an https call using *Invoke-WebRequest*. Since it won't allow the request due to certificate errors, I need to run the following command to disable SSL validation:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```

However, when I attempt to run this command I get the following error:

```
Unable to find type [System.Net.ServicePointManager].
At line:1 char:1
+ [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.ServicePointManager:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

OS: macOS Sierra

To replicate the issue:

- Download PowerShell for OS X from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell
- Install the .pkg
- Type 'powershell' in a terminal
- Attempt to run the command above.

Answer (score 1):

Not really familiar with this, but... the PowerShell for OS X link you provide appears to use .NET Core.  However, `System.Net.ServicePointManager` isn't supported by .NET Core.

Digging around, I'm able to find [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138952/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-in-net-core), which lead to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8165) issue, and then [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7623) issue, but honestly I'm a bit lost on what's going on because the version numbers refer to so many different things.  I can't tell what's current and what's not.

Bottom line is, as far as I can tell, the proper method for .Net Core is supposed to be `Http​Client​Handler.​Server​Certificate​Custom​Validation​Callback` in `System.Net.Http`, but I'm not exactly sure how you refer to that with PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows PowerShell up until version 5, the workaround you are attempting to use was required because the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet did not have a convenient way to ignore certificate checks.

In PowerShell 6+, because of the prevalence of self signed certificates in the Open Source world, Invoke-WebRequest was upgraded to include a lot of new switch parameters to deal with them. In particular take a look at the `-SkipCertificateCheck` parameter in the [documentation for the cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6).

That parameter will allow you to accept an unknown certificate to encrypt your connection as you are attempting to do here.

Comment: Not sure why you don't have lots of upvotes sir. You saved me a huge headache and lots of googling! Thannk you. The -SkipCertificateCheck did it for me