# Ignore SSL connection errors via IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-core, httpclient

I have a problem with a connect from my asp.net core 2.2 project to an https site like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138952/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-in-net-core). I use IHttpClientFactory to create typed HttpClient in Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICustomService, MyCustomService>();
```

And I don't understand, how can I ignore SSL connection problems without creating HttpClient manually like this

```
using (var customHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    customHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback  = (m, c, ch, e) => { return true; };
    using (var customClient = new HttpClient(customHandler)
    {
        // my code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder`:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ICustomService, MyCustomService>()
    .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, c, ch, e) => true
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example in minimal api net 6

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("changeme", m => { }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (m, c, ch, e) => true
});

app.MapGet("/", async (
    IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory) =>
{
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("changeme");
}
```