# How can I disable the SSL Certificate check in the .NET Core http client?

Tags: c#, go, aws-lambda, proxy, tls1.2

I am trying to connect to a website via a proxy. This is happening in an AWS Lambda with .NET Core SDK using an http client. The call looks pretty much like this:

```
handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
 CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
     Proxy = new WebProxy(
                new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("proxyURL"))),
     ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator,
     SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
     ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
};

using(var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
     var content = await client.GetAsync("https://my-website.com/");
}
```

I am not able to make the call to "https://my-website.com/". The call times out without an error message.

However I was able to access the website using Golang and resty in an AWS Lambda, skipping the TLS Check:

```
client := resty.New()
resp, err := client.
    SetProxy(os.Getenv("proxyURL")).
    SetRetryCount(3).SetTimeout(3*time.Second).SetTLSClientConfig(&tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}).
    R().Get("https://my-website.com/")
```

*My question is: how can I achieve the behaviour from my Golang Code in my .NET Core Code?*

Comment: `DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator` already achieves the aim of ignoring certificate validation problems, so: I don't think that is the problem

Comment: It will work for you. Check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496011/10396609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL; DR: The problem lied not within certificate validation, but in a security group rule.**

1. As [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) kindly pointed out, the `DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator` already achieves the aim of ignoring certificate validation problems.
2. After deploying the same code in an EC2 instance in the same VPC and subnet I noticed, that the .NET Core code was making one more HTTP call than the Go code (Although I still do not understand why). The IP adress was not within the allowed IP range of outgoing traffic, thus blocking the request and causing a timeout of the `HttpClient`.