# ASP.NET Core how to send request from a locally hosted Web API to another locally hosted Web API (for testing)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate

I have on one side NoPCommerce on the other side our own REST API. I need that NopCommerce to send a post request to our REST API. That part is done.

I want to test this locally, so I started both projects. NopCommerce runs on `localhost:5001`, our REST API on `localhost:7521`.

When NopCommerce sends the request, I got an SSL error.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding dev certificate on local  using [dotnet dev-certs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs)

Comment: I still receive a AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch error message.

Comment: Okay, you can disable SSL certificate verification them, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138952/bypass-invalid-ssl-certificate-in-net-core). This is for localhost only don't do it in production.