# working with certificates for server connection

Tags: c#, uwp

im trying to transfer code from console app to uwp, in this console app used ServicePointManager that use all certificates, in uwp app i don`t use them and  have exception with text - "A connection with the server could not be established".

The question is - how can i replace ServicePointManager and apply all certifates in uwp(because i don`t know what type of certificate used for this server).

Code of ServicePointManager is listed below:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
(bypassAllCertificateStuff); 

private static bool bypassAllCertificateStuff(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors error)
{
  return true;
}
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: Is the ServicePointManager code you posted about from previously used console app?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to use `HttpClient`, and if this is from the `Windows.Web.Http` namespace, you can add a filter to it, where some kind of certificate errors can be bypassed.
Eg.:

```
using Windows.Web.Http;
using Windows.Web.Http.Filters;

var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted for `ServicePointManager` instructed the client to disregard server certificate validation errors. So, if your server certificate would expire, or if it was issued to a different host, or if it was signed by a certification authority that is not known to your client machine - your calling code would not care and continue communicating with that server. Depending on your requirements, it may or may not be a smart decision to disable that validation. However, if you do want to disable validation, and you use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, you can [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12553854/403431) on StackOverflow.

Also, keep in mind that you can use two HTTP clients in UWP application. For the comparison between the two, see [this link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/).