# How can we use HttpClient in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm writing ASP.Net MVC Core 2.2 Web App. I need to get data from another web server with HTTP or HTTPS. How should I do this?

I wrote code using `HttpClient`.

I have a Controller that gets a message and it works fine but, should I be constructing `HttpClient`?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IUpdateService _updateService;

    public MyController(
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILogger<MyController> logger,
        IUpdateService updateService)
    {
        _env = env;
        _logger = logger;
        _updateService = updateService;
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IAsyncResult> Post([FromBody]Update update)
    {
        using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = Client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
            switch (result.StatusCode)
            {
                case HttpStatusCode.Accepted:
                    return true;
                case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please, don't use using because of the IDispose pattern.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54707165/1498669

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[Microsoft documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

1. Register the `HttpClient` in `ConfigureServices`.

   1a. for [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients)

   ```
   services.AddHttpClient<ITypedClientService, TypedClientService>();
   ```

   1b. for [named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#named-clients)

   ```
   services.AddHttpClient("someClient", c =>
   {
       c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://someaddress.com/");
   });
   ```

   1c. for [Basic usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-usage)

   ```
   services.AddHttpClient();
   ```
2. Inject the `HttpClient` into your controller.

   ```
   [ApiController]
   public class BotController : ControllerBase
   {
       ...
   ```

   2a. for [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients)

   ```
       public BotController(..., ITypedClientService httpClient, ...)
       {
           ...
           _httpClient = httpClient;
           ...
       }
   ```

   2b. for [named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#named-clients)

   ```
       public BotController(..., IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, ...)
       {
           ...
           _httpClient = clientFactory.createClient("someClient");
           ...
       }
   ```

   2c. for [Basic usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-usage)

   ```
       IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory

       public BotController(..., IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, ...)
       {
           ...
           _clientFactory = clientFactory; 
           ...
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Update update)
       {
           ...
           var request = new HttpRequestMessage(
               HttpMethod.Get, 
               "https://someaddress.com/api/resource");
           request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
           request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "YourApp");
           var client = _clientFactory.createClient();
           var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
           ...
       }
   ```

Do not construct `HttpClient` yourself, new is glue. Let `HttpClientFactory` and the framework mangage the lifetimes and instantiation.

**Note**,
With Basic Usage you are dodging the benefits of configuring policies for defined clients.

Comment: Better use [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) instead.

Comment: @poke, that is essentially what I mean

Comment: but I have question how can I send url to service in this way because every time the requested url is deferent?

Comment: @Faraz that is [Basic usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#basic-usage)

Comment: @Faraz, I extended the answer