# Created Teams Message Extension project in VS 2022 but Solution doesn't show teams content as default

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-teams

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAcZj.png)I'm following the youtube video [Teams update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/toolkit-v4/install-teams-toolkit-vs?pivots=visual-studio-v17-7), but when I created my Message Extension teams project it didn't have the info shown in solution explorer like his video shows at 6:57.  Any idea why? I have VS 2022.

Here's the video: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeGRgScvil8)

Here's what my project looks like:

[[image: My Teams Project missing the project folders upon creation]]

In the video, when he creates his teams project in the start it looks like this:
[image]

I'm trying to automate sending build verification details to our group teams chat (not a Team under Teams in MS Teams).

Update:
I found a link that said I needed to update my VS 2022 and try recreating the project so I did that and it had what the youtube video showed in the project.
Now the issue is that (when I start setting up the Teams Message Extension project, I get the error,

> Configurating the dev tunnel to host the port failed. The SSL
> connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote
> certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure:
> RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Following the steps in GettingStarted.md (error is in step 2 above):

1. In the debug dropdown menu, select Dev Tunnels > Create A Tunnel (set authentication type to Public) or select an existing public dev tunnel
2. Right-click your project and select Teams Toolkit > Prepare Teams App Dependencies
3. If prompted, sign in with a Microsoft 365 account for the Teams organization you want
   to install the app to
4. Press F5, or select the Debug > Start Debugging menu in Visual Studio
5. In the launched browser, select the Add button to load the app in Teams
6. Open Windows PowerShell and post a HTTP request to trigger the notification:

I'm not sure if it's my tunnel I created that's the issue, or if I need a developer 365 account for Visual Studio? Or if it's another step not listed before step 2?

[image: tunnels]

Update2:
I noticed at 9:30 in the video they select an existing dev tunnel.  I don't have the dev tunnel selection there like he's doing. But I do have my tunnel activated like I show. I tried creating the project again and selected The most basic Message Extension type application
[image: Basic Message Extension type app]

but get this error when I do step 2 above.

[image: Preparing Teams app dependencies failed]

With this info in the output:

> "name": "MissingDevTunnelError", "message": "No DEV_TUNNEL_URL in
> 'teamsapp.local.yml'. Create a new public dev tunnel in the debug
> dropdown menu (Dev Tunnels), or select an existing one. Alternatively,
> you can fill in the DEV_TUNNEL_URL field in the 'teamsapp.local.yml'
> file.", "stack": null,

Comment: Are you not able to see the code itself or some specific part of it.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft none of the project setup shown in the video showed in my Vs project. It was supposed to be there by default when I create a project of that type.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft any idea why it wouldn't show the teams project setup?

Comment: @Michele We have repro the steps with your youtube vedio its opening solution explorer and works fine.

Comment: @vikram-MSFT I found out I needed to update VS and then I could create the teams project ok.  Now I'm getting  RemoteCertificateNameMismatch error. See Update.

Comment: @Michele Please have a look at this thread-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68204114/remotecertificatenamemismatch-remotecertificatechainerrors-error-message-makin