# How to Add server certificate custom validation

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have to issue when I am calling external service I have the following error
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
after long search I find that I have to add `servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback` to my `HttpClient`
My code is like this

```
 public class ApiClient
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _apiClient;

        public ApiClient(HttpClient apiClient)
        {
            _apiClient = apiClient;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Method to get summary data
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>summary Dto</returns>
        public async Task<SummaryDto> GetSummary()
        {
            var response = await _apiClient.GetAsync("summary");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummaryDto>(result);

            return null;
        }
}
```

and inside startup file:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient>((sp, config) =>
            {
                config.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["ServiceBaseUrl"]);
                config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            });
```

My question is how to add `servercertificatecustomvalidationcallback`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback?view=net-5.0

Comment: Maybe you will find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient/54707165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this in .NET Core.

In Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient<ApiClient>((sp, config) =>
        {
            config.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["ServiceBaseUrl"]);
            config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                //Your Validation Logic Here
                return true; //OR false;
            }
        });
```