# Im trying to access HTTPS url from my android application. I have self signed certificate for my server side(sslcert.cer)

Tags: c#, android, ssl-certificate, httpclient, self-signed

This error shows up when I try to get data from the URI:
[exception details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgWqR.png)
I did some digging on the web and I created a folder in resources called XML with a file [networking_security_config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3Im2.png)
and I added the certificate in the .pem extension on another folder called raw, I used OpenSSL to convert the certificate from .cer to .pem[certificate added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1L6e.png)
Then I went to the androidManifest.xml, in the application block I added the networkSecurityConfig.[androidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5DGE.png)
However, the error is still the same!
Here is the main code! I need your help guys
[image]

Comment: Look at your first link,  You are getting one input stream.  Why do you have two get input streams at bottom of error?

Comment: Please, questions are far easier to read if the text content (mainly code)  is included in them as text instead of images.

Comment: Not sure if in android is the same, but you could check `CertificateValidationCallback`. For example this related question [Allowing Untrusted SSL Certificates with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient/54707165)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.