# How to upload files to Digital Ocean Space with AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, digital-ocean-spaces

I am wanting to create a WinForm application to upload selected files to digital ocean space. You can imagine it works similar to Cyberduck and written in C#. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

***This worked for me to upload files with AWS SDK to Digital Ocean Space :***

> Install-Package AWSSDK.S3

```
public static string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, string filepath)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                string accessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                string secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
                config.ServiceURL = "https://abc1.digitaloceanspaces.com";
                AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                        accessKey,
                        secretKey,
                        config
                        );
                // Create a client
                AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1); //according to your prefered Region 
                try
                {
                    var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
                    var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + filepath, // filepath is your folder name in digital ocean space leave empty if not any.
                        InputStream = file.InputStream,
                        StorageClass = S3StorageClass.StandardInfrequentAccess,
                        Key = file.FileName,
                        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                    };
                    fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
                }
                catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
                {
                    // Exception code here
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Exception code here
            }
            return file.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            // else code here 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever get the error where they said The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Comment: @JainYA No, I didn't get this error.

Comment: @JianYA I facing same issues too. Did you resolve it? run on IIS Express with self-signed SSL

Comment: were you finally able to upload the file? ? they dont have documentation on its web site

Comment: Looks like the Digital Ocean cert is invalid. I think you can can set the `HttpClientFactory` on the `AmazonS3Config` object and ignore SSL errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient @JianYA if you want to create a separate question I'm happy to provide a more substantal answer.